# Append script to ID using short code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code like :

```
<div id="content">
 <div id="widget1"></div>
 <div id="widget89"></div>
 <div id="widget78"></div>
 ..............
 <div id="widget(anyIndex)"></div>
</div>
```

By adding content into widget (HTML/JS widget) I have :

```
<div id="content"
     <div id="widget1">
       <script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery("#widget1").selectme({
                Numpost:4,
                Stylepost:"papa",
                });
    </script>
     </div>
     <div id="widget89">
       <script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery("#widget89").selectme({
                Numpost:7,
                Stylepost:"popo",
                });
       </script>
     </div>

     ..............
     <div id="widget(anyIndex)">.....</div>
 </div>
```

It is so manual and time-consuming.

Now, I want use short code instead of repeating too much Javascript in each div like :

```
<div id="content"
 <div id="widget1">[4][papa]</div>
 <div id="widget89">[7][popo]</div>
 ..............
 <div id="widget(anyIndex)">...</div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
<script>
(function (a) {
    a.selectme = function (c, b) {
        var d = this;
        d.init = function () {
        d.options = a.extend({}, a.selectme.defaultOptions, b);
      ...................something
        };
        d.init()
    };
    a.selectme.defaultOptions = {
        Numpost:4,
        Stylepost:"Enter your style",
    };
    a.fn.selectme = function (b) {
        return this.each(function () {
            (new a.selectme(this, b))
        })
    }
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Notice :Widget(anyindex) is catch automatically. For example: widget89 is set current but I don't know the index of that widget (index = 89), just sure that I am inputting Javascript/Jquery code into it. When I add new widget I will have new index, for example : widget105 or also widget200 (anyindex)

How can I do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is probably a copy paste error, but you are missing the closing `>` to the top divs.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov: thanks. it is not problem for my question. i will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a  way using data attributes in markup and a simple `each` loop to initialize. Add `data-` attributes for the variables you need to specify in plugin.

```
<div id="widget89" data-numpost="7" data-style="popo">
 alert( $('#widget89').data('numpost') );
```

To get index of widgets create a collection of them first to use to index against:

Using `$.each` to intialize the whole collection will give you the  index of widget in collection ( I'm not clear what you need it for):

```
$('[id^=widget]').each(function(idx){
   var $this=$(this), data=$this.data, INDEX=idx;
   $this.selectme({
       Numpost:data.numpost,
       Stylepost:data.style
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks. It is actual solution..But How can I using short-code for current widget?

Comment: It doubles data if i add more ID

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function

```
function setwidget(id,post,style)
{
  jQuery("#"+id).selectme({
                    Numpost:post,
                    Stylepost:style
                    });
}
```

now call like

```
 setwidget("widget1",4,"papa");
setwidget("widget89",7,"popo");
```

Comment: Wouldn't that set all widget divs to have the same `Numpost` and `Stylepost` values?

Comment: Sorry, I want use short code, not by adding Jquery into div. Thanks for your suggesstion. @jasonscript: your right. Not have the same Numpost and Stylepost values in each widget.

Comment: @Rituraj ratan: widget(anyindex) is catch automatically. For example: widget89 is set current but I don't know the index of that widget (index = 89) just sure that I am inputting Javascript/Jquery code into it. When I add new widget I will have new index, for example : widget105 or also widget200 (anyindex)